# hhvm won't change error_log ini setting at runtime

Tags: php, nginx, hhvm

So i'm completely new to hhvm. I've tried to setup a basic nginx and hhvm environment. It works fine, running both php and hack, and outputs errors to `/var/log/hhvm/error.log`.

The problem is that I need to change logfile at runtime, but errors are always only send to `/var/log/hhvm/error.log` (or whatever `/etc/hhvm/server.ini -> hhvm.log.file` is set to). My test php file is:

```
<?php
var_dump(ini_set('error_log', '/var/log/chs.log'));
var_dump(ini_get('error_log'));
error_log('foobar');
```

In the browser it outputs `string(0) "" string(16) "/var/log/chs.log"` as expected. I get the same result when using hack.

My setup is completely standard. Clean Debian with `apt-get install hhvm nginx` and then running `/usr/share/hhvm/install_fastcgi.sh`.

Any suggestions? Has anyone else tried this and made it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, [it is a bug](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/3558). Follow along on the issue tracker to see when it is fixed (or even better, send us a PR to fix it).

Comment: Thanks. I don't think I am the right to fix that :-)